# Prove that $\varphi ^{−1}(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-homomorphism

> Let $\varphi:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism and let $K$ denote a subgroup of $H$. Prove
>   that $\varphi^{−1}(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know how to usually prove something is a subgroup; i.e prove its a group (has identity, is associative, has inverses and is closed under binary operation) and then prove its contained with in the group, but for this I am very confused on what $\varphi^{−1}(K)$ means.

Any help would be great.

Comment: $\varphi^{-1}(K)$ means $g\in G \text{ such that } \varphi(g)\in K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $$\varphi^{-1}(K)=\{g\in G:\varphi(g)\in K\}.
$$

---

The following is a solution to your exercise.

Since $\varphi(e_G)=e_K$, we have $e_G\in \varphi^{-1}(K)$, so $\varphi^{-1}(K)\neq\varnothing$. Also $\varphi^{-1}(K)\subseteq G$ by definition. Thus $\varphi^{-1}(K)$ is a nonempty subset of $G$.

Let $a, b\in\varphi^{-1}(K)$. Then there exist $x, y\in K$ such that $\varphi(a)=x$ and $\varphi(b)=y$. Consider $ab^{-1}$: we have $$\begin{align}\varphi(ab^{-1})&=\varphi(a)\varphi(b^{-1}) \\ &=x\varphi(b)^{-1}\\ &=xy^{-1},\end{align}$$ so $ab^{-1}=\varphi^{-1}(xy^{-1})\in \varphi^{-1}(K)$.

Hence $\varphi^{-1}(K)\le G$ by the one-step subgroup lemma.

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi^{-1}(K)$ denotes the preimage of $K$ under the map $\varphi$.  That is,
$$\varphi^{-1}(K)=\{g\in G:\varphi(g)\in K\}.$$